# How can I compare two Git branches and only list the new commits in the feature/topic (second) branch

Tags: git, github, branch, feature-branch

I have performed the steps below, but when I compare the `develop` branch with the `feature` branch I see two commit messages instead of only just 1 commit that I expect to see. One is the previous commit which is already in `develop` and the other us the latest commit I made in the `feature` branch.

1. I have pulled and merged the local `develop` branch from a remote branch
2. Then have created a new branch off of `develop`
3. Made changes and added those files and `git commit -m "latest changes"` in the `feature` branch
4. Performed `git push` to push the `feature` branch to the remote branch
5. When I compared `develop` to `feature`, I see two commits instead of just one (the one I created in the `feature` branch)

Why is this happening and how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: The merge is a commit if it was not a fast-forward (including representative commit messages in the question would be useful). I recommend _not_ having a local develop branch. Create new feature branches off of origin/develop instead. Then the new branches are naturally starting at the correct remote commit. It also avoids needing to remember to merge/pull-forward a generally needless branch. It’s okay to checkout origin/develop in a detached head mode (eg. to build+test) as well if committing work to feature branches.

Comment: Can you please let me know the command to create a feature branch off origin/develop branch

Comment: Thanks @Petros for editing , Learnt how to make it better

Comment: The process is largely the same as for branching from develop, only there is no need to pull/merge the develop branch. The commands I use go about like: git fetch —tags —all —force ; git checkout origin/develop ; git checkout -b feature/foo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer on your question:** you may see difference between two branches by executing `git log <parent_branch_name>..<your_feature_branch_name>`, for instance `git log develop..feature`.

**About your situation:** As I see situation, the most likely reason for such behaviour is merging develop branch within your local repo. If while merging process (fyi pull operation is combination fetch and merge), merge did not process as fast-forward, then you got another state of develop branch, here could be merge commit, you are able to compare commits hashes.

In order to prevent such situations, you should use `git pull --rebase` command for pulling some local branch.

If you wanted to get latest changes before pushing your local feature branch to the remote server, you could also run `git pull --rebase origin develop` on your feature branch, then commit's tree will look like you just created your feature branch from develop and put all created commits on feature branch after parent's branch commits.

I hope, it will be helpful for you!

Comment: FWIW: I’m a fan of not having a local develop (or other mainline) branches, as I find the process to keep these up-to-date is unnecessary in a feature branch model. Being able to work via remote names (or direct commits, etc.) is one strength of the git model over some alternative SCM models.

Comment: @AGrigorii , I will surely try  `git pull --rebase`  ....What i used to do always is I first `git checkout develop` branch and then run `git fetch origin/develop` and then `git merge origin/develop` and finally I  create a feature branch from the local branch